# Oblique image box with CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I need a CSS solution for this problem. I hope you guys can help me out.

Is there a way to convert this solution with pure CSS? The problem is, the pictures has to stick together.. I tried it with a div that rotates, with overflow hidden and an image inside it, that has the opposite rotate direction. Didn't work that well..

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO! Please don't post answers like the one you did, but edit the original question using the same-name link. Also, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - your question as it stands is not complete.

Comment: Further, for us to help you with your CSS we first need to see your ("*[MCVE]*" HTML and attempted CSS, so we can try and solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this one problem.

Comment: You could use clip-path properties. Take a look this page: http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ It will generates the css for the clip-path dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to stackoverflow, on my next contribution , I will follow the rules. Sorry.

Comment: @Nestoraj thanks! This looks good - I will try it out. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `transform:skew(...);`. It "skews" the container element und "unskews" the content wrapper while overlapping for the skewed section.

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  color: white;
}
.header {
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465420961937-e0eba4dda519);
  height:300px;
  width:100%;
  padding: 0 5%;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
.content .wrapper {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:50px auto 200px;
  width:100%;
  padding:0 5%;
  transform:skew(0deg,-5deg);
  -ms-transform:skew(0deg,-5deg);
  -webkit-transform:skew(0deg,-5deg); 
}
.content {
  z-index:1;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin-top:-100px;
  width:100%;
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1462121457351-9fb0f5622b72);
  transform:skew(0deg,5deg);
  -ms-transform:skew(0deg,5deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform:skew(0deg,5deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.footer .wrapper {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:50px auto 200px;
  width:100%;
  padding:0 5%;
  transform:skew(0deg,5deg);
  -ms-transform:skew(0deg,5deg);
  -webkit-transform:skew(0deg,5deg); 
}
.footer {
  z-index:1;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin-top:-100px;
  width:100%;
  background: url(https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1467173572719-f14b9fb86e5f);
  transform:skew(0deg,-5deg);
  -ms-transform:skew(0deg,-5deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform:skew(0deg,-5deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}
.endpage {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <!-- first element content -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- second element content -->
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- third element content -->
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="endpage">&npsp;</div>
```

Comment: Note that while this is effective it draws so very slowly on Android Marshmallow (Nexus 5x); though I can't really think of a better means of achieving the same aim, unfortunately.

Comment: You mean the images draw slowly? Probably because of their big sizes...